# Why does my link stay on its hover state when on a mobile device?

Tags: css

I could very well have lost it.

My :hover, a:link states do not seem to work on a mobile.

I have a fixed nav at the bottom of the screen:

```
/* nav */
nav#desktop {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-top: 28px;
    z-index: 1002
}
nav#desktop > ul {
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 28px 2.3%
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 675px) {
        nav#desktop > ul {
            position: relative;
            height: 25px;
            overflow: hidden;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 28px 3%
        }
    }
nav#desktop > ul > li {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 400;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 12px;
    position: abolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden
}
nav#desktop a {
    color: #000
}
nav#desktop a:hover {
    color: #8974A7
}
```

On a desktop the `hover` works successfully, as in when you hover it shows purple and then goes back to black.

Why on a mobile, when the `li` item is clicked, does it go purple, and then stay purple.

I did have:

```
nav#desktop a {
    color: #000
}
nav#desktop a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #8974A7
}
```

Thinking `:focus` was behind it, having removed it now; still no change.

Interestingly, I have:

```
#mobile-open #mobile-container > ul {
    position: relative
}
#mobile-open #mobile-container > ul > li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
#mobile-open #mobile-container > ul > li:last-child {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
#mobile-open #mobile-container a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
#mobile-open #mobile-container a:hover {
    color: #ccc
}
```

For links within my open menu, and the two states work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

As you can imagine, `:hover` is almost impossible to truly support on consumer touch devices (there's no detection for when a user is hovering over the screen but not touching it).

So the devices do the best they can, and they end up with what you observe, which is a pretty terrible experience, but you're at the mercy of browser vendors - you're developing on their platforms.

Do what often seems to be done, add a piece of JavaScript to detect (imperfect) user-agent/touch detection and add a class of `touch` to the body element.

And then, everywhere in your CSS you'd have to do this:

```
body:not(.touch) someselector:hover { }
```

Or do the inverse:

```
body.no-touch someselector:hover { ... }
```

If you decide you like the `:hover` implementation of a particular browser vendor when on touch, but not the implementation of another, then you can add further classes to your CSS to target specific browsers/devices.

All solutions are pretty terrible, really.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:active` and `:visited` to change the color after you selected the element.

`:hover` on mobile don't work. Devices try to render it as better as they can but with touch device there's not an `:hover` status.

Comment: Certain devices apply the :hover pseudo class though (e.g. after long press).